# Understanding IP Time to live relation to recvfrom on multiple raw sockets

Tags: c, sockets

It is my first time on sub TCP level and I have to perform some SYN/ACK exchanges "by hand" so with raw sockets and I am having some trouble understanding some fundamentals. I have 2 questions considering raw sockets `SOCK_RAW` and `recvfrom()` set like:

```
int s_raw = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW , IPPROTO_TCP);
```

1. Might sound obvious, but I'm going to be able to receive a specific packet, by calling `recvfrom()` as long as the time-to-live value in the IP header is >0? Or better said once the ttl is zero I won't be able to get the packet anymore via `recvfrom()`, right?
2. If I call `recvfrom()` on different raw sockets ,initialized like above, I will get the packet from all `recvfrom()` calls as long as the ttl is >0? Further applications (for which the packet was designated for) in the background of which I have no direct control of will still receive that package? So the packet is not lost or something else, just because I observe and ignore it on one specific socket instance?

---

EDIT:
Thanks to @AnttiHaapala for reminding me that the result of these two questions might be operating system/kernel specific. I'm using Ubuntu Server ever since (always kept up to date - newest kernel). So I would be primarily interested in linux, but I would appreciate also some few lines about other operating systems.

Comment: Might be operating system, kernel specific too

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6880590/918959

Comment: I.e. not obvious at all, perhaps add your operating system there

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Hello and Thank you for your comment, link and suggestion. I've edited the question according to :D.