# Python3 sniffer problem in mac, why it doesn't work?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, sockets

I am new to socket programming and I wrote this very short python3 code on mac and run.
It can only sniff ping messages. When I open my Chrome and visit [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) it won't receive anything.

It's my code problem or a problem of macOS? And please help me with a correct version of python3 code.

```py
import socket

sniffer = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_ICMP)
sniffer.bind(('', 0))

sniffer.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_HDRINCL, 1)
while True:
    print(sniffer.recvfrom(4096))
```

I've also tried replacing `IPPROTO_ICMP` with `IPPROTO_IP` and `IPPROTO_TCP`. None works.

Comment: I think that `socket.IPPROTO_ICMP` is the culprit. You only ask for ICMP protocol and only see ping requests. You should have better results with `IPPROTO_IP`.

Comment: @SergeBallesta Thank you! But I've tried ```IPPROTO_IP``` as well as ```IPPROTO_TCP```. None works. So it may be a problem of macOS?

Comment: Accessing raw sockets like that ofter requires administrator privileges... Unsure whether related.

Comment: @SergeBallesta I used sudo as admin. I've run it on a linux virtual machine and it worked fine. Now I wonder how to make it work on macOS.

Comment: Sorry I do not use MacOS and I won't be able to help you here...

Comment: Okay. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I met a similar problem like yours when I was programming in C on MacOS

[Strange RAW Socket on Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6878603/strange-raw-socket-on-mac-os-x/6880590#6880590) says that almost all the packets, registered in kernel(including TCP), won't pass rock sockets.
So, you can have a try to `pcap` in Python.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31890560)